# Possible to express expected alignment of pointers?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, llvm

Is there any way to express expected alignment on a pointer, such that the backend is able to make assumptions about the alignment of the data it points to; for instance, SIMD codegen can choose aligned loads/stored where it would otherwise have had to conservatively use unaligned variants for free pointer types. At a higher level, it has some implication about allocation strategies too.

I'm mainly curious to know if this concept is expressible in common IR's (LLVM/GCC, etc), and if no language does support it, COULD they support it?

Edit: to be clear; I'm interested in the "assume this alignment, and accept the consequences if I'm wrong" case, which is the only case that I think is meaningful to the backend/codegen, but I'd be interested if either case is expressible.

Comment: Expected as in "probably this alignment so optimize for that", or as in "assume this alignment and accept UB if I'm wrong"?

Comment: Maybe [std::align](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/align) could be of use?

Comment: Like [__builtin_assume_aligned](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#index-_005f_005fbuiltin_005fassume_005faligned)?